# Changing the timestamp format of LINE chat history in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

I want to do sentiment analysis on my LINE chat history. Here is a sample of the chat history which is a txt. (tab-separated) file.

```
Time            Name    Text
2018/05/03(Thu)
21:00           User1   XXXX
22:00           User2   XXXX
2018/05/04(Fri)
00:10           User1   XXXX
00:30           User2   XXXX
01:00           User2   XXXX
.
.
```

I loaded this txt file above as a data frame in R with 3 columns: Time, Name, and Text. Therefore, the first row and the fourth row of the Name and Text columns will be empty. What I want to do is make a timestamp format like this:

```
Time                Name   Text
2018/05/03 21:00   User1   XXXX
2018/05/03 22:00   User2   XXXX
2018/05/04 00:10   User1   XXXX
2018/05/04 00:30   User2   XXXX
2018/05/04 01:00   User2   XXXX
.
.
```

I know maybe there's no specific function to do this task, but is there any code/loops that we can use? Thank you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In data.table:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(Time = c('2018/05/03(Thu)', '21:00', '22:00', '2018/05/04(Fri)','00:10', '00:30', '01:00'),
                 Name = c(NA, 'User1', 'User2', NA, 'User1', 'User2', 'User2'),
                 text = c(NA, 'XXXX', 'XXXX', NA, 'XXXX', 'XXXX', 'XXXX'))

is_data <- grepl('[[:alpha:]]', DT[, Time])

DT[, Data := Time]

for(i in seq_along(is_data)[-1]) {
  DT[i, Data := fifelse(is_data[i] == TRUE, DT[i, Time], DT[i-1, Data])]
}

DT[, c('Time', 'Data') := .(paste(Data, Time), NULL)]

DT <- copy(DT[!is.na(Name)])

> DT

                    Time  Name text
1: 2018/05/03(Thu) 21:00 User1 XXXX
2: 2018/05/03(Thu) 22:00 User2 XXXX
3: 2018/05/04(Fri) 00:10 User1 XXXX
4: 2018/05/04(Fri) 00:30 User2 XXXX
5: 2018/05/04(Fri) 01:00 User2 XXXX
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`, one way would be:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(idx = cumsum(grepl('\\(', Time))) %>%
  mutate(Time = paste(sub('\\(.*', '', Time)[1], Time)) %>%
  slice(-1) %>% ungroup %>% select(-idx)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  Time             Name  Text 
  <chr>            <fct> <fct>
1 2018/05/03 21:00 User1 XXXX 
2 2018/05/03 22:00 User2 XXXX 
3 2018/05/04 00:10 User1 XXXX 
4 2018/05/04 00:30 User2 XXXX 
5 2018/05/04 01:00 User2 XXXX
```

You can add `%>% mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M'))` at the end to get a proper timestamp format as well.